# About eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

### How the question arose

I'm studying for a Symplectic Geometry exam, and my notes have the following theorem, and a problem arose out of the start of the proof.

> **Theorem**
> Let $P$ be a symmetric positive definite $2n\times2n$ matrix with real coefficients. Then we can find a basis $\mathcal B=\{u_1,\dotsc,u_n,v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^{2n}$ such that:
>
> 1. $\mathcal B$ is Darboux for $(\mathbb R^{2n},\omega_0)$, with $\omega_0$ the standard symplectic form (definition below);
> 2. $\mathcal B$ is orthonormal with respect to the product $\phi_P$ defined by $P$ (i.e. $\phi_P(v,w)=v^TPw$);
> 3. $\phi_P(u_i,u_i)=\phi_P(v_i,v_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

$$\omega_0(v,w)=v^T\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & I \\ -I & 0 \end{array}\right)w\qquad I=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \dots & 1 \end{array}\right)\in M_n(\mathbb R).$$

First of all, we can find a basis $\mathcal D$ that is orthonormal for $\phi_P$, allowing us to assume WLOG that $\phi_P$ is the standard product. Of course, this will, in general, not be Darboux.

$\omega_0$ will be represented, in this $\mathcal D$, by a matrix $A$ satisfying $A^T=-A$. We note that:

$$\overline{iA}^T=(-iA)^T=-iA^T=iA,$$

which means $iA$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues all real, hence $A$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues. So we will have an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^{2n}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $iA$, which are, of course, eigenvectors of $A$ too.

Reasoning on the eigenvalues, we can conclude that a basis of $\mathbb C^{2n}$ exists of the form $\{z_1,\dotsc,z_n,\overline z_1,\dotsc,\overline z_n\}$, where $Az_i=i\alpha_iz_i$ and, of course, $A\overline z_i=-i\alpha_i\overline z_i$, $\alpha_i$ being real for each $i$.

My notes say that this basis can be found orthonormal. And I was like, how?

Thinking back on it, if I choose any o.n.b. of eigenvectors of $iA$, say it's $z_1,\dotsc,z_n,z'_1,\dotsc,z'_n$, we have orthonormality, in particular, for the first $n$ vectors $z_1,\dotsc,z_n$, and that gives us normality for their conjugates, since the norm is left unchanged by conjugation. My main problem back when I first met this proof this afternoon was orthogonality, but suppose $z_1,\dotsc,z_k$ are relative to $i\alpha_1$, then there will have to be $k$ vectors $z'_{i_1},\dotsc,z'_{i_k}$ which are eigenvectors relative to $-i\alpha_1$, and those will span the same eigenspace as $\overline z_1,\dotsc,\overline z_k$, meaning these conjugates will also be orthogonal to all other elements of the o.n.b. we found, so we replace the $z'_{i_j}$ with those conjugates, and go on replacing till we've turned our starting o.n.b. into $z_1,\dotsc,z_n,\overline z_1,\dotsc,\overline z_n$, and orthogonality is preserved.

However, this is what I only just thought up. Back when I first tried to answer the above orthogonality issue, I thought of this:

> Eigenvectors relative to distinct eigenvalues of $iA$ must be orthogonal since $iA$ is hermitian; here we are dealing with $\alpha_1$ and $-\alpha_1$, so we are fine.

But then I tried to prove it, and proved the following.

> If $T$ is a Hermitian matrix, and $v,w$ satisfy $Tv=lambda v,Tw=\mu w$, then either $\lambda=\overline\mu$ or $v,w$ are orthogonal.

*Proof.* $T$ is hermitian, hence $T^T=\overline T$, so:

$$(Tv,w)=v^TT^T\overline w=v^T\overline T\overline w=v^T\overline{Tw}=(v,Tw).$$

(If you take $(v,w)=\overline{v^T}w$, the proof will be slightly different, but the fact that $(Tv,w)=(v,Tw)$ still holds.) That being said, take $v,w$ as in the statement, and:

$$\lambda(v,w)=(\lambda v,w)=(Tv,w)=(v,Tw)=(v,\mu w)=\overline\mu(v,w),$$

hence:

$$(\lambda-\overline\mu)(v,w)=0,$$

yielding the statement.

### The question

The above cannot be true, because if we take $\lambda=\mu\in\mathbb C\smallsetminus\mathbb R$ and $v=w$, then we would get that either $\lambda=\overline\mu$, which is excluded by $\lambda\notin\mathbb R$, or $(v,v)=0$, but a vector cannot be orthogonal to itself unless it's zero. So where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere, actually. You have just forgotten that a hermitian matrix must have real eigenvalues, and taken an easy proof of it as a contradiction to your reasoning. Indeed, your argument is a proof by contradiction: if we exclude both $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and $v=0$, we reach a contradiction, hence either $T$ is not hermitian, or one of the two things we excluded has to hold.

Comment: Be kind to the OP!